# withRequestTimeout is ignored in Playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

when I'm unable to set the timeout when I use the HTTP client from the playframework. This is my code:

```
val request: Future[WSResponse] = WS
    .url(url)
    .withAuth(user, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
    //5 minute timeout in milliseconds
    .withRequestTimeout(300000)
    .put("")
```

This won't give me an error but the request will time out directly after 2 minutes. Is there something else which has to be set so that the timeout is used?

**Update:** I use the 2.4.8 version of playframework. It looks like this version has the following bug: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4846

However, the suggested hotfix isn't working for me eigher.

```
val request: Future[WSResponse] = WS
    .url(url)
    .asInstanceOf[NingWSRequest]
    .copy(requestTimeout = Some(-1))
    .withAuth(user, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
    .withRequestTimeout(-1)
    .put("")
```

Both will give me a timeout after 2 minutes.

Comment: Peter, what do you want to do here? you want to get rid of the time out or set it to something more than two minutes?

Comment: Actually both would be fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee this will work for you, but it seems to work for me and you could potentially adapt it:

```
val httpClient = Try(WS.underlying.asInstanceOf[AsyncHttpClient])
  .getOrElse(throw new NotImplementedError("Unsupported HTTP client"))
val putBuilder = httpClient.preparePut(url)
putBuilder.setRequestTimeout(-1).addHeader(user, "Basic " + password)
val promise = Promise[Response]()
httpClient.executeRequest(putBuilder.build(),
  new AsyncCompletionHandler[Response] {
    def onCompleted(response: Response): Response = {
      promise.success(response)
      response
    }
    def onThrowable(t: Throwable): Unit = {
      promise.failure(t)
      super.onThrowable(t)
    }
  }
)
```

Good luck.